# ScriptReference path set to jquery-1.4.1 conflicts with jquery-1.8.2 - based fancybox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, scriptmanager

I am working on an ASP.NET web application and it has a page using a master page. The master page has the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent">` block on top of the call for the fancy box. The fancy box calls to to jquery-1.8.2.min.js and jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3. Now the page (listing.aspx) using the master page has this code block within the HeadContent ContentPlaceHolder:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" />
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

This is used for the continuous scrolling function for listing.aspx.

On other pages using the master page, the fancybox works fine, but when viewing listing.aspx, it does not recognize the functions of the fancybox anymore. I have tried searching for answers and have tried referencing jquery-1.8.2.min.js too. It does not work. When I tried moving the HeaderContent ContentPlaceHOlder within the master page below the calls to the fancybox, the continuous scrolling would not work. I'm so stumped. Really need your help. THanks.